# angular prevent event if other event run first

Tags: angular, events, event-binding

the situation I am facing now that I have to run method with enter key or blur input.

```
<input type="text" (keyup.enter)="log('enter')" (blur)="log('blur')">
```

and ts

```
log(e) {
console.log(e);}
```

the problem is after user use enter key the method will invoked then the user will also blur and the method will invoked again.
 and that's what I want to prevent.

is there is any way to do that without making if conditions ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you need to do when any one and/or both events fire?

Comment: I need to stop blur if enter run first

Comment: sounds like you hacked your way to focus "next field" on enter key press, and now you wish to unwind the spaghetti with more ingredients

Comment: Sorry, still isn't clear (well at least for me). What is the functionality behind this text box? What happens when (a) Only enter a key (b) Only blur out (c) Do (a) and (b)?

Comment: I do the same functionality in the two cases key enter or blur .
but I don't need to run the function again after enter in blur .

Answer (score 0):

to fix this situation I did that :

```
<input #input type="text" (keyup.enter)="input.blur()" (blur)="log('blur')">
```